# Относится ли алгоритм вычисления факториала к парадигме "Разделяй и властвуй"?

Tags: алгоритм, рекурсия, математическая-индукция

При изучении парадигмы `"Разделяй и властвуй"` попадается пример с вычислением числа Фибоначчи с эффективной двойной рекурсией. И тут все понятно, что задача на первом шаге разбивается на 2 подзадачи с двойной рекурсией, присутствует базовый случай и, действительно, - это парадигма `"Разделяй и властвуй"`.

Тут возникает вопрос:

Относится ли задача с простым рекурсивным вычислением факториала числа к той же парадигме `"Разделяй и властвуй"`?

```py
def recur_factorial(n):
   if n == 1:
       return n
   else:
       return n*recur_factorial(n-1)
```

Я думаю, что не относится, так как тут не вижу разделение задачи на несколько более мелких подзадач, хотя вижу явное присутствие базового случая и рекурсии. Хотелось бы удостовериться в своих рассуждениях.

Comment: Вы видите какую то концептуальную разницу между `f(n)=f(n-1)+f(n-2)` и `f(n)=n*f(n-1)`?

Comment: Нет, не относится. Здесь просто сведение задачи к меньшей размерности

Comment: Однако стоит сказать, что и к Фибоначчи эта парадигма притянута за уши

Comment: "Разделяй и властвуй" в случае чисел Фибоначчи — никак не оптимальное решение...

Comment: @MBo оформите как ответ на вопрос, пожалуйста

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет, рекурсивное вычисление факториала - просто сведение задачи к размерности, меньшей на единицу. Здесь нет выделения двух (или нескольких) подзадач, решения каждой по отдельности, затем объединения результатов (хороший пример - сортировка слиянием).

Пример с числами Фибоначчи тоже не слишком удачный, поскольку подзадачи не являются независимыми, и в результате происходит многократное вычисление одних и тех же величин (что ведет к экспоненциальной сложности вычисления, хотя даже без применения математических хитростей можно посчитать числа Фибоначчи линейно)